# $(X,Y)$ normal, find $P(\mathrm{sign}(X) \neq \mathrm{sign}(Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $(X,Y)$ is a bivariate normal with mean $0$ and $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]=1, E[XY]= \delta$. I think that $P(\mathrm{sign}(X) \neq \mathrm{sign}(Y)) = \frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\delta$ and am wondering what the cleanest way to prove it is. The arccos indicates that there could be a geometric meaning and proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** you can write $$
Y = \delta X+ \sqrt{1 - \delta^2} Z
$$
for some $Z$ independent to  $X,Y$, with normal distribution, centered and of variance 1.